# OpenSSL Connection Issues, Timeout

Tags: ubuntu, openssl

When using OpenSSL on Ubuntu 20.04 I'm not able to connect to any ports other than 80 and 443. When I try to connect to any other port, for example 587, the script hangs and I get no output at all and I have to CONTROL-C to kill the script:

```
// this works
$ openssl s_client -connect postmarkapp.com:80
$ openssl s_client -connect postmarkapp.com:443

// this does not work
$ openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect smtp.postmarkapp.com:587
```

I thought it might be a certificates issue but I've updated those and the issue hasn't improved:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ca-certificates -y
$ sudo update-ca-certificates
```

Everything on this machine is updated to the latest packages, of course.

I checked my firewall, even turned it off entirely, and I still can't make any outbound connections to any site on any port other than 80 or 443.  I tested other versions of Ubuntu and this same issue is on 18 but not on 16.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Check your firewall and any external firewalls.

Comment: Are you able to connect with `telnet smtp.postmarkapp.com 587`?